# Matching the values of two vectors

Tags: r

I have the data frame:

```
AA<-c(4,1,5,3,2,13,17,16,14,15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

BB<-c(3,15,4,2,13,19,20,14,7,12,8,18,11,5,16,17,9,6,10,1)

CC<-c(118,106,115,120,105,111,104,101,102,110,119,108,113,109,114,116,103,107,112,117)

DD<-data.frame(AA,BB,CC)
```

How can I create a vector containing the values of `CC` that correspond the numbers of `BB` matching the numbers of `AA`?

I want the EE to look like this: `115,117,109,118,120,105,116,114,101,106`, (I don't care what happens after row 10)

Comment: Can you add a seed (use `set.seed()` ) so that the output can be matched please

Comment: I will try to do that, but I don't care about these numbers here. I have entirely different data frame, but I can't put it here. I just want to know what code (or whatever it is called) I should write to do this task.

Comment: I used this "sample" function to show that the numbers do not have any pattern.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Your desired output is unclear, so please follow the above advice and provide the desired result.

Comment: Hi mad, thanks for having data / expected output. As the `sample` function is random, we are unable to match your expected outcome to which you provided. Its not exactly clear to me what you want, so seeing a reproducible example would definitely help. (that said i think the use of `match` and `[` will get you to your solution... along the lines of `CC[BB[match(BB, AA)]]` ... maybies???)

Comment: `CC[match(AA, BB)]` ... seems to get you there(ish)

Comment: @user20650 exactly, we can close this now :)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the match function to look for the positions of AA in BB and then just select those positions from CC.

```
DD$CC[match(DD$AA, DD$BB)]
```